# Why is $(10/x)^x$ biggest when $10/x = e$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, exponential-function, maxima-minima

I am definitely not a mathematician.

I was reading about $e$ and I saw this fun thing where your cut up a number then raise the result to the power of the $x$ you divided the number by.

I chose $10$ as the number, $x$ is in the range $1$ to $5$, a numpy array:

`x = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)`

Using `matplotlib`, I made a nice little plot, and sure enough, when $10/x = e$, $(10/x)^x$ is biggest.

I'm not sure I understand why. Could you tell me why this is so?

Comment: look here and click on step-by-step solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%28%2810%2Fx%29%5Ex%29

Comment: @markvs You need to pay to be able to do that.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is free.

Comment: @markvs they mean that to see step-by-step solution you need to use the Pro version. I'm not using the Pro version and can't see the step-by-step solution

Comment: To see the full solution -yes. But in this case a  hint is enough and it is free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = (10/x)^x$. Then your question is to determine which $x$ maximizes this function.

One way to solve this is with calculus. Here, the derivative is given by
$$ f'(x) = \big( \frac{10}{x} \big)^x \big( \log(10/x) - 1\big). $$
Extrema will occur when $f'(x) = 0$ or in limiting behavior. As $x \to 0$, $f(x) \to 1$, and as $x \to \infty$, $f(x) \to 0$. The points where $f'(x) = 0$ are the points where $\log(10/x) - 1 = 0$, which is exactly when $10/x = e$

Either plugging in a value or computing the second derivative, we see that $x = 10/e$ is a maximum, and in fact the global maximum.

Comment: We don't need to look at $f''.$  We have $f'(x)>0$ when $0<x<10/e$ and $f'(x)<0$ when $x>10/e$ so the continuous function $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R $ has a unique maximum at $x=10/e.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to digest it! A question, if I may: The "log" you are using here is log base 10 or the natural log?